# Azure API Connection to teams requires manual authentication (terraform)

Tags: azure, microsoft-teams

I'm deploying an API Connection to Microsoft Teams that is then used by a LogicApp to send data to a channel, the issue I'm having is that, even when the API Connection and the LogicApp get deployed properly, the connection lacks authorization and requires to manually go to the LogicApp or API Connection and do a manual login of the user.

For the deployment I'm using terraform with AzAPI provider with a JSON that describes the connection:

```
{
"displayName": "Microsoft Teams",
"authenticatedUser": {
    "name": "mail@my.com"
},
"overallStatus": "Connected",
"statuses": [
    {
        "status": "Connected"
    }
],
"connectionState": "Enabled",
"parameterValues": {
    "username": "mail@my.com",
    "password": "MY_STRONG_PASSWORD"
},
"customParameterValues": {},
"api": {
    "name": "teams",
    "displayName": "Microsoft Teams",
    "description": "Microsoft Teams enables you to get all your content, tools and conversations in the Team workspace with Office 365.",
    "iconUri": "https://connectoricons-prod.azureedge.net/releases/v1.0.1619/1.0.1619.3185/teams/icon.png",
    "brandColor": "#4B53BC",
    "category": "Standard",
    "id": "/subscriptions/${subscription_id}/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/${location}/managedApis/teams",
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/locations/managedApis"
},
"testLinks": [
    {
        "requestUri": "https://management.azure.com:443/subscriptions/${subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/teams-1/extensions/proxy/beta/me/teamwork?api-version=2018-07-01-preview",
        "method": "get"
    }
],
"testRequests": [
    {
        "body": {
            "request": {
                "method": "get",
                "path": "beta/me/teamwork"
            }
        },
        "requestUri": "https://management.azure.com:443/subscriptions/${subscription_id}/resourceGroups/${resource_group_name}/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/teams-1/dynamicInvoke?api-version=2018-07-01-preview",
        "method": "POST"
    }
]
```

}

I'm able to specify the authenticatedUser but not the password (I tried to include password in the authenticatedUser and parameterValues but it doesn't work), so my question is: is there a way that password for authenticated user be specified so no manual authorization is required? or can a Service Principal be used for the authentication for this connection?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check if it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/authenticate-to-azure?tabs=bash

Comment: Hi Prasad thanks for the comment, sadly it did not help, also, we contacted MS Support and the indicated that there's no way to fully automate API connections authorization to services that use OAuth for security reasons, there's a PS script that can semi-automate the consent but it still asks for creds and goes through MFA step.

https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppConnectionAuth